# Triple nested attributes in ruby. Not sure if I am setting them up right or if they can be done. Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested

I have a triple nested attributes that I am trying to capture all the information for in one form. In short I have an event that has many event_locations which have many event_dates which have many event_roles. I have the form in my event new. I think the issues is in my events model and I need to say that there is going other "accepts_nested_attributes_for" for event_dates and event_roles because right now in the event_params I do get the event and event_location information.

```
events controller
        def create
          @event = Event.new(event_params)
          if @event.save
              redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.'
          else
              render :new
          end
        end

private
   def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:name, :event_details, event_locations_attributes: [:label, :address, :zip, :state, :country, :notes], event_dates_attributes: [:event_date, :start_time, :end_time], event_roles_attributes: [:type, :hourly_rate, :quantity])
```

### end

```
    event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :event_locations, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :event_dates, through: :event_locations
    belongs_to :agency
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_locations, :allow_destroy => true
```

### end

```
event new
<h3> New Event </h3>
    <%= form_for @event do |f| %>
            <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true, placeholder: "Name", :maxlength => 200, class: "form-control title_input_field" %><br>

            <%= f.text_area :event_details, :required => true, placeholder: "What are some of the event details", size: "100x10", class: "input_field2" %> <br>



            <h3> Event Locations </h3>
            <%= f.fields_for :event_locations do |builder| %>
                <%= render "location_fields", :f => builder %>
            <% end %>

            <%= f.submit "Create!", :class => 'submit_button' %>
```

### <% end %>

```
_location_fields.html.erb
<p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <%= f.text_field :label, :required => true, placeholder: "Label", :maxlength => 1000, class: "form-control title_input_field" %><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">      
            <%= f.text_area :notes, :required => true, placeholder: "Notes", :maxlength => 200, class: "form-control title_input_field" %><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-5">      
            <%= f.text_field :address, :required => true, placeholder: "Address", :maxlength => 200, class: "form-control title_input_field" %><br>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-2">  
            <%= f.text_field :state, :required => true, placeholder: "State / Provience", :maxlength => 200, class: "form-control title_input_field" %><br>
        </div>  
        <div class="col-sm-2">  
            <%= f.text_field :country, :required => true, placeholder: "Country", :maxlength => 200, class: "form-control title_input_field" %><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">      
            <%= f.text_field :zip, :required => true, placeholder: "Zip Code", :maxlength => 200, class: "form-control title_input_field" %><br>
        </div>
    </div>      
            <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
            <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Location" %>
</p>
    <%= f.fields_for :event_date do |builder| %>
        <%= render "event_date_fields", :f => builder %>    
    <% end %>
```

--

```
_event_date_fields.html.erb
<p>
    <h3> Event Date </h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' />
                  <%= f.text_field :event_date, placeholder: "Select Event Date", class: "form-control", type:'text' %>
                  <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                  </span>
                </div> <!-- date -->
            </div> <!-- form-group -->
        </div>
        <div id="datepairExample">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <%= f.text_field :start_time, placeholder: "Start Time", class: 'time start form-control' %> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1">to</div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <%= f.text_field :end_time, placeholder: "End Time", class: 'time end form-control' %> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>
    <%= f.label :_destroy, "Remove Date" %>

</p>
<%= f.fields_for :event_role do |builder| %>
    <%= render "event_role_fields", :f => builder %>    
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to allow all the models to allow nested attributes for their direct associations, so:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_locations, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_locations, :allow_destroy => true

class EventLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event_date
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_date, allow_destroy: true

class EventDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :event_role
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_role, allow_destroy: true
```

Then your strong params should look like this:

```
    params.require(:event).permit(:name, :event_details,
      event_locations_attributes: [:label, :address, :zip, :state, :country, :notes,
        event_date_attributes: [:event_date, :start_time, :end_time,
          event_role_attributes: [:type, :hourly_rate, :quantity]]])
```

Comment: The event location can have many event_dates and the event date can have many event_roles.
Where you put has_one :event_date and has_one :event_role when I changed them to has_many :event_dates and has_many :event_roles it doesn't work. Is there something else that would have to change to make them work?

Comment: Yes, but then you will need to change both `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for` to match association names (I assumed they are has_one from fields_for names).

Comment: sorry I just edited my last message to make it more clear

Comment: @BradleyFarquhar - What exactly is not working. Ah, you will also need to update your strong params, for nested attributes they are always `<association_name>_attributes`. One thing that might surprise you that for new records there will be no fields - it is normal and expected as there are no associated records and you will need to build them in the controller.

Comment: Got my params like this:
params.require(:event).permit(:name, :event_details, event_locations_attributes: [:label, :address, :zip, :state, :country, :notes, event_dates_attributes: [:event_date, :start_time, :end_time, event_roles_attributes: [:type, :hourly_rate, :quantity]]])

Comment: strong_params look correct. I have to go to sleep now, ping me an email so we can debug it further tomorrow.